# Go somewhere by ride-hailing?

Tags: word-request

I go to the shopping centre by **Uber/Lyft/...**

How do you say in a gerneal way?
Such as: I go to the shopping centre by ride-hailing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general way, you'd say take a cab or a taxi.  Legally uber etc are not taxis (in the UK at least) and so on their websites they are careful not to use the word "taxi", but when speaking conversationally you don't need to worry about the legal details.

You can also use "uber" in a generic way. Just like you can say "hoover the carpet" even if your vacuum cleaner isn't made by hoover.  You can "get an uber" even it actually isn't uber that you are using.

Or you can explain:

> When I go to the shopping centre I use uber, lyft or another one of those internet-based ride-hailing companies.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on why ride-hailing companies in the UK don't use the word "taxi"?

Comment: "Taxi" is a legal word. A taxi driver has to take various tests. They must be of good character and have a clean record.  The car used as a taxi has to pass various conditions. A taxi can be hailed from the street and can pick up rides from a taxi rank.  An uber or a minicab is not allowed to do this, and must be booked in advance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicabs_of_the_United_Kingdom